# What is the performance of Postgres jsonb_set as compared to MongoDB’s BSON update?

Tags: database, mongodb, postgresql, nosql

Just curious, does `jsonb_set` reads the value, modifies it and rewrite it every time? How does it compare to update operation in mongodb?

For example I have a document
`”table”:{“views”:{“123”:{“val”:”234”}}}`

And the operation I want to proceed is to modify the value under `val`.

The SQL statement would look like

```
UPDATE atable SET data = jsonb_set(data, '...', '...', '...', TRUE)
```

Comment: The answer will depend on the SQL statement - can you share that?

Comment: for example, I will need to set the new data with the following `SET data = jsonb_set(data, '{"table", "views", "123", "val"}', '"456"', TRUE)`, so `”table”:{“views”:{“123”:{“val”:”234”}}}` can be updated to `”table”:{“views”:{“123”:{“val”:”456”}}}` @LaurenzAlbe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the PostgreSQL side of things:

If you `UPDATE` a table row in PostgreSQL, a new version of the complete row is written (the old version of the row is left in the table to satisfy concurrent read requests). Also, `jsonb_set` returns a new `jsonb` object, it does not modify the object passed as first argument.

If you frequently want to modify parts of larger JSON objects, you will end up writing much more data than you would want. That is part of the PostgreSQL architecture.

For large objects, you might be better off normalizing the data to the extent that each such update affects a smaller table.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz this answers my question! Just wondering for one to many relationships, is there a way postgres can accelerate the where operation on foreign keys? For example I will have one `Table` mapped to multiple `View`s, and I will have to put a `tableId` as the foreign key under `View`, scanning through the whole `View` table every time for finding the views under a specific `Table` with `tableId` does not seem to be so efficient to me (and I will have one `View` mapped to multiple other table as well! so this is a tree structure basically), and that's why I am looking at jsonb solution

Comment: That's why you [index your foreign keys](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/index-your-foreign-key/), then that is never problem. My opinion is that you will usually be better off with a relational data model with foreign keys.

Comment: oh great thanks Laurenz, thanks for pointing me there.